# calling a fortran function makes the program hang

Tags: c++, fortran

I am trying to call functions from a static Fortran library in C++.

Depending on the problem size, my program starts hanging on the initial call to Fortran library function. I can not understand the reason of this problem...

Just as an example, if the problem size is 133k, the program starts without hanging and ends normally. However, if I increase the problem size to 365k or more, these large problems cause the hanging in the program in the first function call. Both intel and gnu-compilers result in the same behaviour.

What could be the reason of this hang?

Edit: OS: Linux, what I checked was the stack size of my shell, the environment variblaes specific to the library, btw the library is the Watson Sparse matrix package, a sparse linear solver, and the problem size is the size of the matrix operators that are inputs to the solver. I can not post any code since there are a lot dependencies and it will make the process more complex.

Comment: Have you run your program through valgrind to make sure you're not doing anything "bad"? You should try very hard to reduce your problem to a minimal test case that you _can_ post here?

Comment: this is what I am busy with now... checking for leaks on the problem that works...

Comment: Have you run the application inside the debugger and forced it to break to see where the application has hung?

Comment: Yes, I am jumping into the code in my C++ class constructor where I am calling this Fortran function. and it is that exact call that it starts to hang...

Comment: Measure memory consumption as a function of problem size for a range of sizes which do not cause the program to hang.  Draw a graph, extrapolate, draw some conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

How much memory do you have in the machine? How much swap?

If swap is heavily used, you might end up with lots of time spent reading and writing to swap which will make the call *really* slow.

If the algorithm used in the Fortran library is of a higher complexity, you might very well get (much) longer call times with more input.